# Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I kept getting following exception when tried to navigate to my error page inside of handleError() , I am using the latest version of Angular 4.0.2.
I purposely triggered an The error was triggered an "TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined" error on the landing page to test global error redirection, and it didn't work out.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorService implements ErrorHandler{
  router:Router;
  isInErrorState:boolean = false;

  constructor(private injector:Injector){

  }
  handleError(error) {
    console.log("ERROR",error);
    this.router = this.injector.get(Router);
    if(!this.isInErrorState){

      this.isInErrorState = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);

    }


  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: 'error', component: GlobalErrorComponent}
  ])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:26681:19) [angular]
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet

Comment: where you are using this component, there is the problem. add more code to help you further

Comment: I created a plunker to show the issue. My intention is to redirect to the error page when exception occurs, but it doesn't.  you can trigger error by enable line 16 of ContactComponent or comment out to see no exception scenario 
 Thanks! https://plnkr.co/edit/HhYYHnqAOHzFAvKc7o58?p=preview

Comment: Did you get the solution ?